# RSpec - If I avoid using let, let and before, how to achieve same functionality?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have heard that it is a best practice to avoid `its, let, let!, specify, before,` and `subject` in RSpec.

In regards to `let, let!` and `before`, how can I perform setup tasks if not using these?

Comment: Where did you hear this? That doesn't seem like best practices at all. Maybe `specify` and `its` but the rest are actually very useful and clean up your tests a lot.

Comment: @LeoCorrea The guys of thoughtbot [Here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/guides/tree/master/best-practices#testing)

Comment: I've certainly learned a lot in the 6 years since I asked this!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whoever wrote those best practices actually wants to just say "don't use RSpec".  It's insane to avoid using core features and still think you can get things done well.  Can you link to these best practices?  I'd love to read them and see if they're justified or just some j-random-guy's opinion.

Avoid `before` and `let`?  What?  Really?

Avoid `specify`, I guess, it's just older syntax for `it`.

Avoid a specific `subject` call?  I guess, if your code lives in an idealistic fantasy land.  Strive to minimize it and use implicit subjects?  Sure.

Avoid `its`?  It's awesome!  Why avoid it?  Self-documenting one-line specs?  How horrible.

Comment: Sometimes I avoid using `its` over a nice description of what is being tested. However, I agree with you. That doesn't seem like best practices whatsoever

Comment: @LeoCorrea Sometimes a description is better, for sure!  Always use your judgement and write good code.  I guess that's a best practice in itself. :)

Comment: I came across this question on SO after reading [this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/guides/tree/master/best-practices#testing). Think that is the main source of the question.

Answer (score 6):

**The source:** Some folks asked about the source of all of this. I think that this came from the [thoughtbot best practices guides](https://github.com/thoughtbot/guides/tree/master/best-practices#testing).

**The answer:** After read that guideline i almost freak out too but after doing some research i came across this very well explained post from the same guys [Let's Not](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/lets-not). Is a really good reading with a lot of insightful advises about testing and good practices in general.

There is some general misunderstanding of that guideline. Is only saying "avoid" not "don't use". The result code will be more clear and more maintainable.
I will quote some points that the post reflects:

- (...) there are a few features of RSpec's DSL that are frequently overused, leading to an increase in test maintenance and a decrease in test readability.
- Until you need to break out the big guns like shared examples, avoid DSL constructs like subject, let, its, and before. Stick to your old friends: variables, methods, and classes.

It makes a lot of sense to me.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Because none of the answers here are addressing the actual question and instead giving their opinion on the practices mentioned, I felt the need to add another answer even if it's 7 6 years since it was asked:

All of the "problematic" DSL methods can be replaced with plain old Ruby methods. You can still be DRY without having to use methods that deviate attention to different parts of the code.

> The following code is directly extracted from the book Rails 5 Test Prescriptions by Noel Rappin

```
describe "estimates" do
  let(:project) { Project.new }
  let(:done) { Task.new(size: 2, completed: true) }
  let(:small_not_done) { Task.new(size: 1) }
  let(:large_not_done) { Task.new(size: 4) }

  before(:example) do
    project.tasks = [done, small_not_done, large_not_done]
  end

  it "can calculate total size" do
    expect(project.total_size).to eq(7)
  end

  it "can calculate remaining size" do
    expect(project.remaining_size).to eq(5)
  end
end
```

Replacing with plain Ruby methods

```
describe "estimates" do

  it "can calculate total size" do
    project = build_new_project
    project.tasks = build_done_small_and_large_tasks

    expect(project.total_size).to eq(7)
  end

  it "can calculate remaining size" do
    project = build_new_project
    project.tasks = build_done_small_and_large_tasks

    expect(project.remaining_size).to eq(5)
  end

  def build_new_project
    Project.new
  end

  def build_new_task(size=1, completed=false)
    Task.new(size: size, completed: completed)
  end

  def build_done_small_and_large_tasks
    tasks = []
    tasks << build_task(2, true)
    tasks << build_task(1, false)
    tasks << build_task(4, false)
    tasks
  end
end
```

In my opinion and Thoughtbot's opinions, there are advantages for this approach:

- Each test tells a story about how to use the code that you'll write later
- Each test is self contained and descriptive, ideally you won't have to navigate through the whole file to immediately understand what goes on in each test (but this will depend on your ability to write good tests too)
- No dependency between examples
- No **"Mystery Guest"** antipattern

On another note, the point is to show in each test explicitly as possible each phase of testing

- Setup - get the conditions correct for the test
- Exercise - perform the thing that you're testing
- Verification - verify that the exercise did what you expected
- Teardown - undo any conditions that shouldn't persist post-test
  (this should be done by Rspec automatically, but anything explicit can go in an after block)

Example:

```
it "can calculate total size" do
  # Setup
  project = build_new_project
  project.tasks = build_done_small_and_large_tasks

  # Exercise and verification 
  # Exercise is the "total_size" method, because that is what we are testing
  # Verification is the expectations of what should happen after the exercise
  expect(project.total_size).to eq(7)
end
# Teardown is performed by Rspec, you may also perform it yourself in   after blocks
```

And to conclude, one company's style guide will never fit all purposes or other companies. As far as I can comprehend this approach is especially useful for **Test-Driven Development** where code needs to be driven by what each failing test suggests to fix the test. So to say that you **shouldn't** follow this approach is rather subjective. It's got good arguments but also some drawbacks and as always you should weigh them in and stick to whatever suits you best. In my case, I find these tests much easier to read and more useful to understanding each module of the application, rather than simply having a suit to inform you when something breaks, I like having code that documents itself. This approach will let you see clearly how your future code will be used and what to expect from each condition. **RSpec is more than just DSL methods.**

For more on TDD and how to follow this approach to testing, check how to [Tell a Story With Your Tests](https://thoughtbot.com/upcase/videos/telling-a-story-with-your-tests)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to research best practices for rspec some resources I use are:

- [Better Specs](http://betterspecs.org/)
- [The Rspec Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356379)

Comment: betterspecs.org is a great site!

Answer (score 1):

I definitely agree with Nick, these guidelines should not be followed.

I've recently written a blog post about building your spec in the right way. It has a thorough walkthrough of taking a "bad" written test suite and making it a blast.

You can read it [here](http://railsadventures.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/11-steps-to-make-your-rspec-specs-awesome/).

Comment: Great article.  I want to vote this up, but the rule "use before :all instead of before :each when possible" is wrong, as discussed in the comments to the linked article.  It should be "Strongly prefer before :each instead of before :all."  Many people won't read the comments that explain that, so the article gets a fail on that one point.  The rest of it is very good!

Comment: Hi Wayne, thanks for the input.
I do think that `before :all` blocks has an important role in reducing test suit runtime. It just have to be used carefully, as stated in the comments and noted in the post itself.

Comment: Erez, Thanks for your response.  I agree it has an important use.  My disagreement is that the name of the rule places optimization first, and mentions correctness as a modification of the rule.  I think it should place correctness first, and mention optimization as a modification of the rule (in other words, sometimes you must risk being incorrect in order to be fast enough).  Optimization should play a "walk-on part," being used when necessary, but it should not play a leading role.

Comment: In any case, I'm being a bit petty.  Voted up.

Answer (score 1):

> I have heard that it is a best practice

It would be helpful if you can quote some source. I believe the statements you heard are very inaccurate.

> avoid `its`

I personally don't use `its`, but it's a matter of preference. Since [`its` is a short-hand method](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-99/docs/subject/attribute-of-subject), you can normally use the extended version.

> avoid `let`, `let!`

There is no reason to avoid them. The [official documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-99/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) do no discourage them, in fact they are actively advertised.

Technically speaking, you can replace them by defining a method.

```
let(:foo) { 1 }
```

is "equivalent" to

```
def foo
  @foo ||= 1
end
```

but as you can see, using `let` is more convenient and effective.

> avoid `specify`

`specify` is an alias of `it`.

> avoid `before`

This doesn't make sense. There is no way to avoid `before` if you need it, and the official documentation doesn't deprecate it.

> avoid `subject`

Absolutely false. The documentation encourages its use.

---

Bottom line. I strongly believe that what you heard is false. Have a look at [the  documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-99/docs) to learn how to effectively use RSpec.